# How do I change the title's font color?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm a beginner and I'm working on a Shopping Cart app using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and EF Core.

However, I want to change the text color of the title in my home page.

You may find below the method Index() from **HomeController.cs** file that is used in order to have title in my page:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var pies = _pieRepository.GetAllPies().OrderBy(p => p.Name);

    var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel()
    {
        Pies = pies.ToList(),
        Title = "Welcome to Alexander's Shop!"
    };

    return View(homeViewModel);
}
```

How can I change the title's font color in order to be white?

Thanks.

Comment: Design is a part of front-end. Give a CSS class to the title and add some style.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Model.Your TextName,"",new{@class="SomeClass"})

<style>
.SomeClass{
color:Red
}
</style>
```